# Selenium Grid Error: Hub is Down or Not Responding on EC2 (AWS) Server

Tags: java, selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm trying to connect to an EC2 (Amazon Web Services) remote instance/server via Selenum Grid from my local machine. I have set

my local machine as a "hub" and can view the config on localhost (so I know it was set correctly).

However, when I try to set the remote server as a "grid" and connect to my local machine I am unable to do so succesfully. The

code I am using on the remote server is:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node  -hub http://REMOTEIP:4444/grid/register
```

The error I keep getting is: Unable to connect.. Hub is down or not responding..

I tried different variations like adding -hubHost and -host as parameter (as per the following threads on SO

[Selenium Grid2 - Remote Node not connecting to HUB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682742/selenium-grid2-remote-node-not-connecting-to-hub) and

[Setting up Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263190/setting-up-selenium-grid)) but whatever I do I keep getting the same error.

The other threads where all about connecting to a remote server that is not running on AWS platform. Perhaps there are certain

configurations needed for AWS? I have installed all appropiate jar files on the remote machine..

I have a dynamic IP but I don't think this is the problem because I have not changed my IP address (i.e, IP matches my current IP).

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to ping remote machine and directly connect to that port? Maybe it's firewall issue?

Comment: I disabled my firewall to test if this was causing the problem but still getting error. The error I get now is "error sending registration request" and "hub is down or not responding". Thanks

Comment: Can  you ping the remote machine as Sergey suggested?

Comment: I'm getting "request timed out" when I try to ping..

Answer (score 0):

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node  -hub http://REMOTEIP:4444/grid/register

The REMOTEIP(in your example) should be the IP of the hub, and not of the remote instance. Are you sure you have the correct IP set ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the REMOTEIP with your adresse of the nodes. check when you configure the hub. with which adresse the nodes are registered.
in my case:  INFO - Nodes should register to http://xxx.xxx.xx:4444/grid/register/

So the code when you use the remote server should be:
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node  -hub http://xxx.xxx.xx:4444/grid/register